# How can I achieve textpos relative positioning in a document set to absolute positioning?

Tags: calculations, textpos, relative

This is as close as I've got, but I can't work out how to do the calculation so that textblock accepts it:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=93.884mm,paperwidth=68.992mm,margin=0mm,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage{zref-user}
\usepackage{zref-abspos}
\usepackage{calc}

\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1mm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1mm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

  This is a document in absolute textpos mode, but I will also need to use relative positioning in it.

  \zsavepos{test}
  \def\dimtomm #1{\the\numexpr \dimexpr #1\relax*635/118407168\relax }
  \begin{textblock}{59}(\dimtomm{\zposx{test}sp},93.884mm-\dimtomm{\zposy{test}sp})
    % ! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)
    I WANT THIS TEXTBLOCK TO BE POSITIONED RELATIVELY
  \end{textblock}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use dimensions with `textblock`. It expects to receive simple numbers corresponding to the numbers of horizontal and vertical units. But you are trying to feed it `mm`, I think, which won't work. (If you need to use dimensions, consider `textblock*`.)

Here's a working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=93.884mm,paperwidth=68.992mm,margin=0mm,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage{zref-user}
\usepackage{zref-abspos}
\usepackage{calc}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{1mm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{1mm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{document}
This is a document in absolute textpos mode, but I will also need to use relative positioning in it.

\hspace*{5mm}\zsavepos{test}
\edef\thingone{\numexpr\zposx{test}*635/118407168}
\edef\thingtwo{\numexpr\zposy{test}*635/118407168}
\edef\thingthree{\numexpr 93-\thingtwo}
\begin{textblock}{59}(\thingone,\thingthree)
  I WANT THIS TEXTBLOCK TO BE POSITIONED RELATIVELY
\end{textblock}
\end{document}
```

[image: relatively positioned block]